# jQuery ajax like file upload with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, file-upload

http://mypokerpartner.com/

Test is at the link above.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('input[type="file"]').click();
});
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

When using the form's browse button the file is submitted on change. when using the link for "A" IE throws an error of `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.`

I want for the anchor link to invoke the file dialog and when a file is selected it auto submits the file to the iframe for a non-reloading file upload

EDIT:
Looks only to be a problem in IE9

Thanks in advance

Comment: In IE7-8 it works as expected. Exactly what browser version are you having problems with? http://jsfiddle.net/qk3Ur/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason unknown to me, while the `input` field had any `name attribute` it would IE would throw the error. Removing the `name attribute` for the file `input field` fixed this.